# NOT IN operator in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

Any idea why NOT IN operator is not working in this query

```
SELECT  ?p0 ?o0 
WHERE { 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin>  ?p0 ?o0 . 
FILTER (?p0 NOT IN("rdfs:label", "dbo:abstract", "dbo:wikiPageWikiLink", "dbp:image", "dbp:wikiPageUsesTemplate", "rdfs:comment", "rdfs:label", "rdfs:seeAlso", "owl:sameAs", "dbo:wikiPageExternalLink", "dbo:wikiPageID", "dbo:wikiPageLength", "dbo:wikiPageRevisionID", "dbp:image")). 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you use [string literals](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QSynLiterals) instead of [prefixed IRIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#prefNames) inside the `NOT IN` operator. Just remove all `"` and it will work well:

```
SELECT  ?p0 ?o0 
WHERE { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin>  ?p0 ?o0 . 
  FILTER (?p0 NOT IN(rdfs:label, dbo:abstract, dbo:wikiPageWikiLink, dbp:image, dbp:wikiPageUsesTemplate, rdfs:comment, rdfs:label, rdfs:seeAlso, owl:sameAs, dbo:wikiPageExternalLink, dbo:wikiPageID, dbo:wikiPageLength, dbo:wikiPageRevisionID, dbp:image)).
}
```

[Try out](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT++%3Fp0+%3Fo0+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FBerlin%3E++%3Fp0+%3Fo0+.+%0D%0AFILTER+%28%3Fp0+NOT+IN%28rdfs%3Alabel%2C+dbo%3Aabstract%2C+dbo%3AwikiPageWikiLink%2C+dbp%3Aimage%2C+dbp%3AwikiPageUsesTemplate%2C+rdfs%3Acomment%2C+rdfs%3Alabel%2C+rdfs%3AseeAlso%2C+owl%3AsameAs%2C+dbo%3AwikiPageExternalLink%2C+dbo%3AwikiPageID%2C+dbo%3AwikiPageLength%2C+dbo%3AwikiPageRevisionID%2C+dbp%3Aimage%29%29.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on)